# Using a SQL update in a foreach loop php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am trying to update a table with multiple checkbox. Each row has a checkbox.
I want to change value of column **status** by setting 1 instead of 0 if the checkbox is checked.
Below is an example of the way the form is laid out:

```
<tbody>
<?php
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
  ?> 
<?php echo "<td class='form-group form-md-line-input'>  <input type='checkbox' name='formation[]' id='myFormation[]' class='form-check-input' ></td>" ?>
<?php echo "<td class='form-group form-md-line-input'>  <input class='form-control' type='text' name='status' value='0'> </td>" ?>
</tbody>
```

An example of the way the query is laid out:

```
// update the product
 function update(){

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

           if(!empty($_POST['formulaire'])) {

         foreach($_POST['formulaire'] as $value){
                                                            
                                                            
             $query = "UPDATE 
                " . $this->table_name . " 
            SET 
                Statut = 1
                  WHERE ...........;
             $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    
     $stmt->bindParam(':ID', $this->ID);
    
     // execute the query
     if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
     }else{
        return false;
     }
               }

             }

         }
 }
```

My problem is how to write the query.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `status` input needs to be an array, doesn't it? Otherwise it'll only reflect a single value for all of your checkboxes. Where is the unique ID for the query coming from, the thing that identifies which row you need to update?

Comment: Hello, Yes The ID identifies the row that in want to update

Comment: I'm not sure how you can link the `status` and `formation` array elements reliably. I'm sure there must be a way, I'd probably hack it and build the checkbox name to contain the ID, something like "CB001" if your ID was "001", then `foreach` through the `$_POST` array looking for entries that start with CB and extract the ID from the name. Must be a better way.